# LoadError in Articles#index cannot load such file -- omniauth for twitter authentication in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter, omniauth

I am trying twitter authentication for my blog. I have already implemented Devise in my application. So I am following `http://railscasts.com/episodes/235-devise-and-omniauth-revised` video. When I completed all the steps mentioned in this video and tried to access my application, I am getting `cannot load such file -- omniauth` error. Details of error message are following.

```
Extracted source (around line #12):

9:   <div id="tabs"> 
10:   <ul id="tabs">
11:     <li><div style="color:#82b548;font-size: 0.9em;">  <%= time_tag(article.created_at.in_time_zone("Asia/Calcutta")) %> </div></li>
12:     <li> <div style="color:#4895d1; font-size: 0.9em;">  <%= article.user.username if article.user %></div></li>
13:     <% if !article.nil? %>
14:       <li><div style="color:#CCD600; font-size: 0.9em;">  <%= article.comments.size %> comments </div></li>
15:       <li><div style="color:#CCD600; font-size: 0.9em;"> <%= link_to article.tags.collect(&:name).join(" ") %> </div></li>
Rails.root: f:/kuta/billi

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/models/user.rb:15:in `<class:User>'
app/models/user.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
app/views/articles/index.html.erb:12:in `block in _app_views_articles_index_html_erb__265352894_31994844'
app/views/articles/index.html.erb:6:in `each'
app/views/articles/index.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_articles_index_html_erb__265352894_31994844'
```

**models/user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
  attr_accessible :title, :body
  validates_confirmation_of :password
  validates_presence_of :password, :on => :create
  validates_presence_of :email, :on => :create
  validates_presence_of :username, :on => :create
  validates_uniqueness_of :email
  validates_uniqueness_of :username
    has_many :articles, :order => "created_at DESC"
    has_many :comments
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, 
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :omniauthable,
   :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
   where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_create do |user|
    user.provider = auth.provider
    user.uid = auth.uid
    user.username = auth.info.nickname
    end
  end

  def self.new_with_session(params, session)
    if session["devise.user_attritubes"]
      new(session["devise.user_attributes"], without_protection: true) do |user|
      user.attributes = params
      user.valid?
      end
    else
     super
    end
  end

  def password_required?
   super && provider.blank?
  end

end
```

I think error lies in 12 line of my code and it is regarding user. But exactly I do not know what I am missing. let me know if you need more code to be pasted. Thanks

Comment: Please post your `app/models/user.rb`

Comment: hi kiddorails, I have updated question with user.rb. Thanks for response.

Comment: You have properly added and bundled the `omniauth-twitter` gem in your `Gemfile`, right?

Comment: hi kiddorails, yes.  here is: gem "omniauth", "~> 1.1.1"
gem "omniauth-twitter", "~> 0.0.14"

Comment: hi Kiddorails, when I removed omniauthable from user.rb model, It works somehow. Do we really need omniauthable in user.rb. But it does not work fully.

Comment: I have an application where I'm using both `Devise` and `omniauth-facebok`. I have `:omniauthable` strategy for devise in `user.rb`, and it is working just fine. Still contemplating what may be the issue. You have added all required column/migrations, restarted server right?